# How to Install WiX Extensions for VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 Professional, and am trying to replicate my Vs2013 development environment including the installation of WiX extensions.  Unfortunately when I attempt to install the Votive2017.vsix file I get an error message:

[image: VSIX Installer Error Message]

Can someone please assist.  I have been struggling with this for the last three hours now, and it is driving me insane.  My VS2017 install seems to be complete, sufficient at any rate to compile, run and debug the VS solution that I have ported over from VS2013.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Guys please find below the content of the install log as requested:

```
 24/06/2019 11:00:44 - System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.5.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
 File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.get_Host()
    at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.CreateExtensionEngine()
    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
    at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionEngineForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs, Boolean isRepairSupported)
    at VSIXInstaller.App.TryAddSkuToValidSkuList(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension extension, List`1 validSKUs, Boolean isRepairSupported)

 WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
 To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
 Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
 To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

 24/06/2019 11:00:44 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
    at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
    at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
    at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: click on "View Install Log" and post the error message here

Comment: Please show the Install log. And update your vs to latest version before you install the extension. Also, try opening your Developer Command Prompt for VS2017, and type command `devenv /updateconfiguration`, **wait several seconds(maybe longer)** until its execution finishes. And then delete the package folder (Which contains votive.pkgdef), after that rerun your xxx.vsix to check if it finds your VS2017 product.(If it's the second time when you run the xx.vsix)

Comment: Original post edited to include the error from the Installlog

Comment: @PaulJohnson Please let me know if my answer helps. And i suggest you can check what the result if you install other free extensions from [this marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vs).

Comment: Well, should not fail when VS2017 is properly installed.  Note that the MSFT employee is giving you bad info, this DLL is always present in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies directory.  Have a look-see, you'll probably have to spin the update/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that the extension wants to load the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll, since I've installed it successfully in one Community Edition where the assembly not exists.

1.Please download the latest Votive2017.vsix [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension&ssr=false#overview).

2.And if the installation fails again for trying load that assembly:

**If the assembly exists:**

- Update VS2017 to latest version. If it's already latest 15.9.13, try [vs repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).(For 15.9.13, the `Assembly version` should be 15.8.0.0)
- Make sure you've got the Admin permission of your current machine. Check the [FileLoadException Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileloadexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) and you'll find this exception has something to do with OS permission.

**If the assembly not exists:**

- Still I recommend you update VS to latest version. Latest version 15.9.13 has fixed some issues.
- After that, as a workaround you can `Go Tools menu =>Get Tools and Features` to install `VS Extension Development workload` which contains the assembly it wants to load.
- Then please make sure you run the Windows as Admin when you trying to install the extension.

In addition: The path of the assembly should be:(Thanks for Hans's reminder!)

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension installed for me by doing following thing:

Step 1: Create two certificate files with the name as mentioned.

Step 2: Right click and install the certificate for local computer with auto option (restarted the computer twice but i don't know, is there any need.)

Step 3 : I have started the Visual Studio 2019 with "Run as Administrator" and open the "Manage Extensions" to install the wix using Online tab. After closing the visual studio 2019, it start installing and a success message appeared.

I have created the two files using notepad to create certificates using below text as mentioned in the following link:
[Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2019 Extension fails to install with invalid certificate](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6053)

Certificates text:
DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA.cer

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

```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```

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

NET Foundation Projects Code Signing CA.cer

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

```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```

-----END CERTIFICATE-----